# Destroy the [combine]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [combine](/questions/tagged/combine) is described as:

> Combining is the action of using different concepts or functions together to perform only one in the end.

And well, its a bit of a mess.  Everything from combining data sets to combining functions to... well, I wouldn't be surprised if there was someone trying to write a unit test for the hardware of a combine (farm equipment) in there either.

A sample of the questions with the tag:

- [MySQL Combine 2 rows into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465189/mysql-combine-2-rows-into-one)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227987/combine-2-physical-hard-drives-into-one
- [Combining two MySQL queries from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889044/combining-two-mysql-queries-from-the-same-table)

It fails the meta meta tag test - could a question stand with only this tag?  And the answer is no.  It gives no value to the question isn't in the title of the question already.

Make it go away.  Please.

Comment: Do we have a spare crowbar for Trogdor?  You can't defeat the `[combine]` without a crowbar.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That tag has been put...

[image: broken combines]

...out to pasture.

Comment: [YYYEEEEAAAAAHHHHHH!!!!!!!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bh9RJ.jpg)